# Is it possible to tell if a file is valid after an incomplete torrent download?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent, file-corruption

I'm trying to downloading a torrent file using uTorrent but it only gets to 99.3%... no one else is seeding anymore.

If I open the torrent folder I can see all the individual files I'm looking for.  I know uTorrent creates all the file names and preallocates their space.  I am able to open some of the files without obvious issues...

Is it possible to tell which files were not completed?  Is there a method in uTorrent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

µTorrent shows the percentage for each file in the "Files" tab – if it says 100%, then the file is complete.

[image: Files tab]

You can also enable *Preferences → General → Append .!ut to incomplete files* if you want incomplete files to be named differently.

Comment: I did the append to file and that worked.  I dont know what "files" tab you are talking about.  Could you explain where this is?

Comment: @Keltan: See screenshot in the updated answer.

Comment: gotcha.  i had it disabled.